# How to search on Twitter but not the user name?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

I tried to search for

> Shadow Onyx

on Twitter, which is for Pokemon Go, but the user with the name "Shadow Onyx" kept on showing up (I need to sort by "latest"), so to use advanced search, I used

> Shadow Onyx not @Darkeclipse19

because the user id of the user "Shadow Onyx" is @Darkeclipse19

But it can't find anything.  To double check my search words, I also used

> onyx not @Darkeclipse19

which should return all "onyx" posts excluding that user, but again it returned nothing, which is strange. So I tried to search using "onyx" and it showed many results not from that user.

So what should I use to get result for Pokemon's Shadow Onyx but not the user "Shadow Onyx"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude usernames and handles while searching twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127425/how-to-exclude-usernames-and-handles-while-searching-twitter)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-` (a minus-sign) to negate.

You can use `from:<userid>` to refer to a Twitter account.

Putting those together, you can search for:

```
Shadow Onyx -from:darkeclipse19
```

This will search for tweets containing both "Shadow" and "Onyx" (put quotes around them if you want to force it to look for them as a phrase), but will exclude any tweets from the user darkeclipse19.